# php strip_tags, allow PHP tags?

Tags: php, strip-tags

I found a lot of topics asking to keep some html tags but I didn't find any which wanted to keep the php tags !

I want something like this :

```
$myString = '<i> Hello, my name is <?php echo $firstName ?> and I'm <?php echo $age ?> </i> <div> my other div content </div>';
$myBeautifulString = strip_tags($myString, '<?php');
```

and the result I would :

```
var_dump($myBeautifulString);
==> 
'Hello, my name is <?php echo $firstName ?> and I'm <?php echo $age ?> my other div content'
```

I need to put the content of this string into a file so I absolutely need to keep the php tags ! The values to fill will be given only after.

Comment: As code highlighting shows such string is a syntax error.

Comment: I know, I need to put the $myBeautifulString in a file and I fill the variables after. It was just to simplify the example

Comment: It will not work this way.

Comment: I know, that's why I said : "I want something like this" and not : "this code is working", I don't know how to keep the php tags and remove all the html tags

Comment: PHP tags inside your string will not work as you expect. Instead of finding how to fix unfixable, move to another solution, __without__ php tags in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

> Note:
>
> HTML comments and PHP tags are also stripped. ***This is hardcoded and can not be changed with allowable_tags***.

(*My emphesis*)

You claim to have read the manual but seem not to have noticed this important caveat. So your solution to retain `<?php` ... `?>` within your string is to not use `strip_tags` function at all and to make your own function with a custom list of tags to remove.

(*Basic example only*):

```
function my_strip_tags(string $string, array $tags){
     $outputString = $string;
     foreach($tags as $tag){
         $outputString = str_ireplace($tag, '', $outputString);
     }
     unset($tag);
     return $outputString;
}
```

Comment: Didn't read this note.... sorry. You're right, yeah it was what I did first but if it could be done in one line it would have been great haha :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Martin ah just 3 min late :)

Answer (score 1):

I used `token_get_all`, and `str_replace` to do this:

```
<?php

$myString = '<i> Hello, my name is <?php echo $firstName ?> and I\'m <?php echo $age ?> </i> <div> my other div content </div>';

function remove_html_tag($input)
{
  $to_return = $input;
  $tokens = token_get_all($input);
  foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (token_name($token[0]) == 'T_INLINE_HTML') {
      $to_return = str_replace($token[1], strip_tags($token[1]), $to_return);
    }
  }
  return $to_return;
}

function strip_html($input)
{
  return filter_var($input, FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => 'remove_html_tag']);
}

var_dump(strip_html($myString));
```

Output:

```
string(94) " Hello, my name is <?php echo $firstName ?> and I'm <?php echo $age ?>   my other div content "
```

Demo: https://eval.in/823595

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-name.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's prettier than the solution I have right now :) Nice one !

Answer (score 0):

Why not concatenate the string instead?

```
$myString = "Hello, my name is " .$firstName. " and i'm ".$age. "</i>";
```

Comment: I can't concatenate the strings, I recover the string with the php tags through another API

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of strip_tags specifies the tags which are allowed. all other tags will be removed.

visit https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp for more information

You haven't added a , to separate the two parameters

Comment: I have alllowed php tags, I want to allow php tags, but it doesn't work this way, that's why I asked this question. I already read the docs

Comment: Visit the site I mentioned in the above answer, you should have a , separating the 2 parameters

Comment: Yes, was a typo while writing the question sorry. I had it in my code, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
   echo $myString = "<i> Hello, my name is {$firstName} and I\'m {$age} </i> <div> my other div content </div>";

    ?>
```

If you have a string containing in the single Quote and use single qoute as a part of the string than it will break your string so escape your string like this `I\'m`.

Comment: sorry but in my actual string I don't have any single quotes, this string was just for the example ^^' so it's not the problem of single/double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the starting single code  and enclose the string inside double code like below,

```
echo $myString = "<i> Hello, my name is $firstName and I'm  $age  </i> <div> my other div content </div>";
```

running [code](https://eval.in/823540)

Comment: I know this can be a way to fill the variables but that's not my point here. I need to put the content of the string inside a file. and the string needs to have the php tags, so I need to keep the "<?php"